# Changing li height moves parent height

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chv6403m/2/)

The problem is that when changing the height of the active tab, it grows downward, leaving a space between the bottom-border and the non-selected tabs. Is there a way to make it grow upward? Or some other way to solve this problem?

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #888;
}

.active {
  background: #bbb;
  height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Tab 1</li>
  <li>Tab 2</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Disabling `height: 36px;` from `active` css class does resolve the spacing problem. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/chv6403m/5/)

Comment: @AhsN Yes, but I do want the active tab to be taller than the non active ones

Comment: You can add `line-height` and manipulate it with that. Here's a fiddle for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/chv6403m/7/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: bottom;` like this:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #888;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I added a default margin of 6px to the top of the li-elements. When the selected element is active, it removes the margin so it has the space to increase the height while staying in the same place.

Try it out:

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #888;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
.active {
  margin-top: 0;
  background: #bbb;
  height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Tab 1</li>
  <li>Tab 2</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `vertical-align:bottom;` into your li, and then when it resizes it keeps the text on the bottom.

It might be worthwhile to rethink how you do this though, and just have a border or padding at the top that changes color, so the whole tab and contents dont move when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing height, change the border-top like this-

```
.active
{
   background: #bbb;
   border-top: 8px #bbb solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chv6403m/6/)**

Just adding `padding` to the `active` class do the work :

```
.active
{
    background: #bbb;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

It's regular behaivor. Check my solution

http://jsfiddle.net/chv6403m/9/

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Tab 1</span></li>
    <li><span>Tab 2</span></li>
    <li><span>Tab 3</span></li>
</ul>


ul
{
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    padding: 0;
    height: 30px;
}

li
{
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
}

li span
{
    vertical-align: top;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #888;
    height: 30px;
}
.active span
{   
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: #bbb;
    height: 36px;
}
```